# Random shutdown after minutes for macbook pro 15" 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, shutdown

I'm having this problem driving me crazy since some days.

My macbook just turns off after around 1 minute of being logged in.

- I reset completely macOS thinking it would be a Software Issue but nothing.
- I though it was an hardware issue but if I use the guest safari mode it doesn't happend, or also if I install the OS in recovery (which lasts 40 mins or more) I have no shutdowns... so can it be hardware?
- CPU temp and fans are ok, same with battery.
- Bluetooth and WIFI are turned off thinking it was a driver problem, but nothing
- No useful logs in console and all ok running hardware test
- Reset SMC and PRAM

Here's the latest logs before shutdown: https://gist.github.com/dariobanfi/6464faed360005041d9cc1a6895c1712

I am getting crazy... any idea what could cause this??

Comment: You say, "no useful logs in console". Does that mean that there are no kernel panic or MacOS crash reports? There should at least be a shutdown report. Can you edit your question to post the System log information for one of these shutdown/startup iterations?

Comment: NoahL I posted the logs from system.log, I can't see any insightful error message but let me know if you do. No panic/crash report errors when I turn on again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by some unknown hardware problem.
Logic board and display have been changed but the problem still persisted.
Apple Store gave me a new laptop at the end.

Comment: I wonder if we could rephrase this answer?  Nice work writing "an hardware" instead of "a hardware" by the way.

Comment: Oh my god, I did a spelling mistake, I should commit suicide...

Comment: I am most sorry!  I was trying to say that it was **good** that you used _an_ rather than _a_.  There was no sarcasm intended.  It's a fairly well known rule among English speakers, although perhaps not so much US English.

Comment: As for the rephrasing, I didn't spell out what I thought we might change.  Perhaps something very minor:  phrase it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Ok sorry, I was having a bad day and thought it was sarcasm.

Comment: Don't mention it, Ambi.  It's too easy to mis-read questions and comments here.

Comment: Grammar police just letting you know that 'a' is correct. 'an' should be used if the next word starts with a vowel. An engine. A textbook. A hardware fault. No offense intended in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what *I reset completely macOS* means? However, the first two things I'd do now are testing to see what happens in Safe Mode and to also reset the System Management Controller.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps boot your MBP into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Use the computer for a while and take note of what happens (i.e. is the issue still present, etc)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Once you've booted normally again use the computer for a while and take note of what happens (i.e. is the issue still present, etc)

**Reset the SMC**

If the issue is still present I would reset the SMC. For your particular MBP, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

Let me know how things went after doing each of the above.

Comment: By resetting completely the OS I mean that I wiped my HD and installed Sierra cleanly.
I did already reset the SMC and trying now in safe mode, and no restarts yet! What could it mean?

Comment: If it continues to work in Safe Mode and then the problem returns when booted normally, it's practically 100% certain not to be a hardware issue. However, starting in Safe Mode can also rectify things - so if it's fine in Safe Mode you do need to try booting normally to check whether the issue has been resolved. In a nutshell, if it works okay in Safe Mode and then not normally afterwards, the problem is something you have 'added' to the system (software, hardware, driver, etc). Doing this will narrow down your troubleshooting steps because troubleshooting is a process of elimination.